# How do I get the number of bars elapsed year-to-date since beginning of the year?

Tags: pine-script

I would like to get the number of bars elapsed year-to-date since the beginning of the year in pine-script.

I am using pine-script v5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ta.barssince()` function counts the number of bars since the last time a condition was true.
`ta.change()` function checks for changes in a value.

You can combine those functions, and check the amount of bars since the last time a year changed:

```
barsSinceBeginingOfYear = ta.barssince(ta.change(time("12M")))
```